# Is there a word for the availability of a gas, normalized for pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, terminology, ideal-gas, gas

As a bit of background of what I'm getting at, consider that for the purposes of humans breathing and getting oxygen into their blood, 20% oxygen at 1 atm is equivalent to 100% oxygen at .2 atm.  These two gas makeups share the "availability" or "abundance" of oxygen. Is there a more formal word to describe this property of the gas mixture/pressure situation?

Comment: Partial pressure?

Comment: Concentration? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration

Comment: I think Time4Tea nailed it with partial pressure! It's too bad I can't mark him correct because it is a comment instead of an answer...